# Dont sort specific column of table on Jquery ui sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a table with jquery ui sortable and i dont want sort the first column, my table is something like that

```
Pos | Name | Age
----------------------
GK  | Dani | 16
ZQ  | Joe  | 17
```

JS

```
$(function(){
  $('#players').sortable();
});
```

Html:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Pos</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="players">
    <tr>
      <td>Gk</td>
      <td>Dani</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ZQ</td>
      <td>Joe</td>
      <td>11</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Dont matter how I sort the lines I dont want that **Pos** collumn be sorted too, following my code, **GK** always have to stay on line one and **ZQ** always on line 2, I read [this section](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items) of Jquery ui documentation but i confess that i dont understand how to apply this to my scenario.

Comment: Do you have to use only one table? I would suggest having 2 tables with 1 table for the first column which should not be sortable and 1 table for the rest of the columns which should be sortable and you can apply the sortable for the 2nd table. I do not think the link you have given talks about your problem. It will disable entire rows based on class names

Answer (score 0):

You can use two tables. In first you will have Pos, in second - other data. And then you can apply .sortable() to the second table.

Code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Pos</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Gk</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ZQ</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="players">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Dani</td>
                        <td>16</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Joe</td>
                        <td>11</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/UZm5U/1/)